# binlog decoder no longer working

Tags: scripts, 21.04, binary

I have a decoder script for work which used to work fine on Ubuntu 20, but after upgrading to 21, it's showing this message:

```
root@Ubuntu:/work/logs# decoding-script traces.bl

UUID App 1 Subsys 176 not registered!

root@Ubuntu:/work/logs# file /usr/local/bin/decoding-script

/usr/local/bin/decoding-script: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.34, BuildID[sha1]=30a94dbba68d40c0fe8e45881135cd8ee1d0862f, stripped
```

I have a 64bit version, showing the same result

```
root@Ubuntu:/work/logs# file /usr/local/bin/decoding-script64

/usr/local/bin/decoding-script64: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.34, BuildID[sha1]=a67b75647f8076e06556b38c0a4bd951463809ad, stripped
root@Ubuntu:/work/logs# decoding-script64 traces.bl

UUID App 1 Subsys 208 not registered!
```

I am a 1000% sure there is no issues with the script itself.

Comment: NB: It's a program, not a script. The output of the `file` command proves that.

Comment: Look in the documentation of the `decoding-script` program what that message means. If it isn't documented, ask the program author. Nobody without access to the source code of the program can tell you what that error message means. That doesn't mean the cause of the problem lies in the program, but the fact that it emits inintelligible error messages is in itself an issue.

Comment: NB2: It's a really bad idea to run application programs as `root` like you do. There's no reason why a `decoding-script` program should require super-user privilege. Run it with your regular user.

Comment: @Tilman, thanks for the reply, I guess this is not a generic issue as I though. appreciate your assistance.